# Forcing a single horizontal Nav in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to have a horizontal navbar, containing three equally sized nav-pills.

When I drop down to a smaller screen resolution (iphone 5) the third item always drops to a new line, and grows to full width.

How do I achieve a single line horizontal layout for all reasonable resolutions?

It does work when I set the py-1 class to py-0 but I like the look of extra padding.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <section class="container py-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill navtop">
                        <li class="nav-item px-1 ">
                            <a class="nav-link active " href="https://example.com/home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-1 ">
                            <a class="nav-link active " href="https://example.com/meetings">Meetings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item px-1 ">
                            <a class="nav-link active " href="https://example.com/courses">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see how the `py-0` makes any difference. Also define what you mean by reasonable resolutions? At this point it's not wrapping until screen width < 340px which seems reasonble to me.

Comment: On my setup I notice it on iphone 5 settings in chrome dev tools.The first two pills split the width, and the third pill drops down a line and becomes full width.

I can use the px-md-1 and px-sm-0, but I want to know why this behavior happens.

Comment: It wraps when there is not enough space. The container has a max width, the nav-item and links have horizontal padding, etc... Please clarify the question and the specific expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a number of extra containers (which you don't need) -

I removed the containers and added extra CSS for the padding (you can remove it/adjust it if you wish)

**Updated**

I also reduced the container's left/right padding (from 15px to 5px) to make room for the pills in iPhone 5/SE resolutions as per OP's comment - see image below

[image]

See demo below

```css
/* this gives you extra padding on the right-left of each menu item */

.nav-pills li.nav-item {
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill navtop">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="https://example.com/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="https://example.com/meetings">Meetings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="https://example.com/courses">Courses</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. My question deals with supporting iPhone 5s resolutions. You'll notice when opening up the chrome developer tools and selecting iPhone 5, the first two pills split the width of the line, then the final pill takes full width on a new line.

Comment: @prithee I just reduced the padding between pills and they do not overlap anymore... the padding (or spacing) between each element is the culprit here.

Comment: @prithee I am glad I could help :)